# How to find clients for my indexing service

Tags: indexing

I am interested in making indexes for books. I believe I am very good at it, and others (authors, publishers) have told me so as well. Can you share with me if you have any suggestions how I can acquire leads for potential customers? Which people to contact, which authors, which publishers? Thank you!

Comment: I am sort of at a loss as to what exactly you are offering.  Most publishing programs or word processors include a function to generate a keyword index.  You flag the words in the text and the word appears in the index with page numbers automatically.  Are you doing the work of generating the index by hand, or are you simply flagging the words in the text?

Comment: I do the whole job. In fact I would offer you a free sample if you want to give me a book or a champion of a book that's around 30 pages I can show you what sort of our product I'm able to produce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can connect with self-published authors and book layout designers? Since indexing needs to be done after the interior formatting is completely finished, it might be good to work with designers who can recommend you for that next step.

I did look into creating a gig for indexing on Fiverr a few weeks ago (I've indexed a couple cookbooks and thought I'd like to do more), but I couldn't find a category during gig setup that it would fit in exactly. Other freelance websites like UpWork might make it easier to specifically offer indexing. I know Reedsy has a category specifically for indexing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be happy to follow any leads for example if you have specific people that you know are looking for an index

Answer (score 1):

**Target Your Audience:**

**Authors**: Unsurprisingly the self-published writers seek the help of indexing companies, but occasionally they don’t enthusiastic about the indexing process. Try approaching sites which provide self-publishing platforms like KDP (Kindle Direct Publishing) and IngramSpark to see if they would offer you a space to push your service. Another idea you might consider is, for example, joining an online forum or community of authors in order to introduce yourself and the abilities you have.

**Small Presses**: In case the small-sized publishing houses do not have in-house indexers they might be happy to outsource some work. Contact the local and university publishing houses in your place or those who specialize in genres you are about and if they have interest in your project.

**Build Your Online Presence**:

**Freelancer Platforms:** To be visible on the platforms of freelancing like Upwork or Fiver that indicate your indexing skills along with positive crowdsourcing are useful to create your profile.

**Website/Portfolio:** On having your site or online portfolio, it’s a way to present your services to a professional audience. Also mention about indexing experience, areas of expertise, rates, and client quotes in your article.

**Social Media**: In addition to social media groups for writers, editing, and publisher, you too should consider this option. Share some related indexing articles on blogs and join a discussion which help you get recognition as an expert. From the lessons, we have learnt that together everyone achieves more. Working in groups especially with the students from different classes, sense of unity builds.

**Indexing Associations:** Membership in indexing societies like the American Society for Indexing (ASI) or the Chartered Institute of Library and Information Professionals (CILIP) will make a huge difference. Such communities not only provide you networking options but also access to career board.

**Cold Emailing:** Explore do the journal publishers and editors who might want your indexing services. Write the email we deliberately in a professional manner where you need to be kind and self-confident and also include your portfolio’s link.

Comment: Thank you! Did you use ChatGPT? Totally fine if so. Just wondering if I could detect that.